# How to perform destroy task in rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator, scaffolding

In my generator:

```
 module MyNamespace
   class ScaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator
     # bunch of remove_hook_for

     def create_my_model
       MyNamespace::MyModelGenerator.start
     end
   end
 end
```

And it generates everything as need, but how to handle destroy command with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `MyNamespace::MyModelGenerator.start`
I used `invoke MyNamespace::MyModelGenerator` and it works great.